# Recibir un $_POST ocultando formulario

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl, submit

Estoy intentando conseguir recibir una varible por el método POST sin mostrar el formulario en el HTML. Es decir, algo así:

**Código en mi servidor**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="dato" value="1">
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Código en otro servidor remoto**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dato'])){
    echo '¡POST recibido!';
}
```

Pero sin que el usuario vea el código HTML de ese formulario en el código fuente del navegador. Quiero que se quede en el PHP del servidor. Algo así como un `Header('Location:http://')` pero que pueda enviar variables de tipo POST:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters

He visto soluciones basadas en AJAX que podrían crear el formulario y, sin que casi llegue a verse, hacer un `submit()` pero, si desactiva en JS, descubre toda la tostada.

Estoy mirando también cURL, pero quiero que el navegador me lleve a la web que procesa el formulario, no que se quede todo en variables en mi propio servidor sin llevarme al otro. Con este código consigo que envíe al servidor esas variables por POST, pero no consigo que me lleve al otro servidor, tal y como haría un `Header('Location:http://...');`

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://...");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'dato'=>'1234',
]);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Me consta que la pregunta es muy abierta pero, antes de estudiarme cURL, me gustaría que alguien me confirmara si voy por buen camino.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Que es lo que quieres conseguir? No tiene mucho sentido que no tengas en el código html algo que necesitas... Quizás tu problema es otro y lo has enfocado de una manera extraña?

Comment: Si es del lado del servidor, cuando cargas el formulario, setea el valor deseado en una variable de sesión y listo.

Comment: Ok, entiendo la confusión: mi servidor le envía el POST a otro servidor. Modifico la pregunta para aclararlo. Si lo muestro en el HTML lo puede ver todo el mundo, y en el formulario envío datos que deberían ser internos y quedarse en el PHP

Answer (score 0):

leyendo las respuestas de los comentarios a tu pregunta, quizás esto te pueda ayudar.

En principio aprender curl nunca es mala idea. Tarde o temprano lo necesitarás, además te da un margen más ancho en debug.

Dicho eso, file_get_contents también tiene su potencial. Con esto enviarías un POST a otro sitio. el array de $data serían los parámetros del post. En el array de las opciones especifica el método y el header, aunque ahí veas 'http', no hace referencia al protocolo de la web que te conectes.

```
$url = 'https://ejemplo.com/';
$data = array('dato' => '1234');
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === false) { 
die("Error enviando post"); 
}

var_dump($result);
```